# Smarty - url function with parameter

Tags: symfony, parameters, routes, request, smarty

I am using smarty in my symfony3 application.

I would like to generate an url with parameters in smarty based on symfony routing-system:

```
<a href="{{ url('activation') }}">Activate</a>
```

This part creates a normal url like:

```
http://example.com/activation
```

What i would like create:

```
http://example.com/activation?key=param
```

Anyone knows how to create these params and pass them to the url?

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 {{ url('activation', {'key':'param'}) }}
```